# JavaFX - Loading image using facebook graph URL

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, javafx

Creating a desktop application using JavaFX that gets a list of users from an API with a URL for each user profile image, some images are loaded from the server and some others from facebook. The URL for the images that should be loaded from facebook is built using facebook graph. However, in the browser the image loads normally, but in the application i must be doing something wrong.

i am loading these images to a map so i dont have to request the image each time, here is the code :

```
/**
 * @author Asendar
 *
 */
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class UserAvatarModel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(UserAvatarModel.class);
    /**
     * default avatar (use when user has no image)
     */
    public static final Image DEFAULT_IMAGE = ImageLoader.instance.loadImage("default-avatar");

    /**
     * caching the images
     */
    private static final Map<String, Image> IMG_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    public static Image getUserAvatar(User user) {

        if (user.getAvatarUrl() == null)
            return DEFAULT_IMAGE;

        Image img = IMG_MAP.get(user.getAvatarUrl());

        if (img == null) {
            LOG.debug("registering new image, URL : " + user.getAvatarUrl());
            img = new Image(user.getAvatarUrl());
            LOG.debug("image loaded ? : " + (img.isError() ? "ERROR" : "SUCCESS"));

            IMG_MAP.put(user.getAvatarUrl(), img);
        }
        return img;

    }

}
```

The problem is `img.isError()` is true for all images with URL : `http://graph.facebook.com`

Console (replaced the id with xxxxxxxx) its loading fine on the browser:

```
    01:44:50,983 DEBUG com.ro.terminal.model.user.UserAvatarModel : registering new image, URL : http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/xxxxxxxx/picture?type=large
    01:44:51,382 DEBUG com.ro.terminal.model.user.UserAvatarModel : image loaded ? : ERROR
    01:44:52,371 DEBUG com.ro.terminal.model.user.UserAvatarModel : registering new image, URL : http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/xxxxxxxx/picture?type=large
    01:44:52,526 DEBUG com.ro.terminal.model.user.UserAvatarModel : image loaded ? : ERROR
    01:44:53,826 DEBUG com.ro.terminal.model.user.UserAvatarModel : registering new image, URL : https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Dus_SnL_n7Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/1nLwm-HfoBs/photo.jpg?sz=50
    01:44:55,442 DEBUG com.ro.terminal.model.user.UserAvatarModel : image loaded ? : SUCCESS
```